# Keep Session Attributes after logout in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, session, spring-security

I'm creating a web shop using JSP and Spring for a school project.
The website must be usable without being connected (except for payment), so I can add items to my cart even if I'm not connected.
Items in cart are saved as Session Attributes.

My problem is, when the user is connected and has items in the cart, if he logs out, all the Session Attributes will be deleted and thus the cart is cleared. It's not practical for users who have multiple accounts (i.e. pro and private accounts) and want to switch the another one to make the payment.

Is there a way to keep a certain Session Attribute after logout ?

Here is how I call the logout in my JSP page :

```
<a href="<spring:url value='/logout'/>">
   <spring:message code='logout'/>
</a>
```

It's the default call from Spring Security.

Here is my security configuration (`WebSecurityConfiguration.java`) :

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable(); 

        http
                .authorizeRequests() 
                .antMatchers(AUTHORIZED_REQUESTS_ADMIN).hasRole("ADMIN") 
                .antMatchers(AUTHORIZED_REQUESTS_ANYBODY).permitAll() 
                .antMatchers(STATIC_RESOURCES).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated() 
                .and()
                .formLogin() // We define the login part here.
                .successHandler(new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler()) 
                .loginPage(LOGIN_REQUEST) 
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .failureUrl("/error.jsp")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                //.logoutUrl("")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/home") 
                .permitAll();
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you clearing out or resetting `session storage` in any of your files? By default, as long as a particular tab is open, the `session ` data for that tab should not clear. I'm not too familiar with `Spring Security`, but potentially the `logout`, `authenticated` or redirection methods on `http` could be clearing the session storage.

Comment: You should use client side cookies for these situations.

Comment: @Sal yes, the `logout` method was resetting session storage and I was looking for a way to prevent it. I found the (easy, shame on me) solution and posted an answer below. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution (it was right under my eyes) :
adding `.invalidateHttpSession(false)` in the `configure` function seems to be what I was looking for.

My `WebSecurityConfiguration.java` looks like that now :

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable(); 

        http
                .authorizeRequests() 
                .antMatchers(AUTHORIZED_REQUESTS_ADMIN).hasRole("ADMIN") 
                .antMatchers(AUTHORIZED_REQUESTS_ANYBODY).permitAll() 
                .antMatchers(STATIC_RESOURCES).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated() 
                .and()
                .formLogin() // We define the login part here.
                .successHandler(new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler()) 
                .loginPage(LOGIN_REQUEST) 
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .failureUrl("/error.jsp")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                //.logoutUrl("")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/home") 
                .permitAll()
                .invalidateHttpSession(false);
    }
```

Thanks for your help guys